# Is there a list of moderators and diamond moderators for ELU? If so where is it?

Tags: support

It's pretty normal on forums to have lists of moderators. However, after looking around I haven't found a list for ELU.

Am I just looking in the wrong place or doesn't such a list exist?

If not why not? It's sometimes useful to be able to contact moderators. (I have a reason to at the moment)

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators

Comment: Do you mean the SE community mods when you say "diamond moderators"? All moderators have diamonds.

Comment: Related (possible dupe): [Has ELU more moderators than those on the list?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/6640/8019).

Comment: all the moderators have diamonds, don't they? How else would we know otherwise. Are there double moderators among us?! Did you try the search box and typing "mod" or "moderators"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Visit the [Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) via the *help* dropdown at the top of any page.

   > [image]
2. There among other categories you will find "Reputation & Moderation", with the very first question getting you [one step closer to your goal](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators):

   > [image]
3. On that page by scrolling to the very bottom you will find the links you seek:

   > [image]

Here they are in plain text for your convenience:

> Find out who the [moderators for this site](https://english.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) are, or explore a list of [moderators on all Stack Exchange sites](http://stackexchange.com/about/moderators).

Alternatively, you can skip all that nonsense and just go directly to [Users](https://english.stackexchange.com/users) (right under the site title) → [Moderators](https://english.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) (tab in the upper right corner).

Comment: And they are listed in alphabetical order by username.